# Declaring Array Size with a User Input Variable in C++. Different results in different IDE's?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, visual-studio-2015, codeblocks

I need to create a program where the user enters the desired size of an array and the C++ code then creates it and subsequently allows data entry into it.

This works in the Code Blocks IDE but not in Visual Studio Community 2015

When I put the following code in CodeBlocks Version 13.12 it works

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int count;
    cout << "Making the Array" << endl;
    cout << "How many elements in the array " << endl;
    cin >> count;
    int flex_array[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i = i + 1)
    {
        cout << "Enter the " << i << " term " << endl;
        cin >> flex_array[i];
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < count; j = j + 1)
    {
        cout << "The " << j << " th term has the value " << flex_array[j] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, if I enter the same code in Visual Studio 2015 (i.e. Version 14.0.25425), I get the error:

> expression must have a constant value

Any idea why this occurs?

Comment: You don't need to show the same code snippet twice.

Answer (score 5):

C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). Some compilers implement is as an *extension* though, but it's still not a standard feature of the C++ language and it is not portable.

If you want a run-time variable length array use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead:

```
std::vector<int> flex_array(count);
```

Comment: Thanks , need to add #include<vector> in the start of the code. STD doesn't seem to contain this. The compiler gives the message namespace std has no member vector

Comment: @ctd2015: STD don't exist. std (lowercase) is a namespace. It's empty, until some declarations will fill it. Those declarations are inside the <vector> header, taht's part of the C++ standard: see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header